# How to catch SQLException in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here i tried to catch the sql exception using innerexception in SMO Ojects.In Sqlserver
i am getting this error message

```
Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test_sp_syntaxtext, Line 124
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list.
```

But by using this code

```
catch (Exception ex)
          {
           ErrorFlag = true;
           //ex.Source.ToString();
           e2dInsertAndGenerateErrorLog(ex.InnerException.Message.ToString(), FileName, "CHECKINAPPLY", PathName, "ErrorLog.Err");
          }
```

i am getting this

```
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list.
```

I need to cache this line also

```
Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test_sp_syntaxtext, Line 124
```

Any Suggestion?

EDIT:

```
  StreamReader str = new StreamReader(FiletextBox.Text.ToString());
  string script = str.ReadToEnd();
  str.Dispose();
  SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=xx;database=xxx;User id=sx;Password=xxxx");
  Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
  server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```

Comment: You seem to be getting the innerException what about the top level execption message too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [SQLException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception(v=VS.100).aspx).

```
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.Errors.Count; i++)
        {
            errorMessages.Append("Index #" + i + "\n" +
                "Message: " + ex.Errors[i].Message + "\n" +
                "LineNumber: " + ex.Errors[i].LineNumber + "\n" +
                "Source: " + ex.Errors[i].Source + "\n" +
                "Procedure: " + ex.Errors[i].Procedure + "\n");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(errorMessages.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: look at my edit section for this sqlexception will not be catched as the error occurs is of ExecutionFailureException.

Comment: The ExecutionFailureException exception is raised when an execution failure is encountered on the connection to the server.

Comment: Do you like to handle it or fix it here ?

Comment: "An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch." --> this is the errormessage i am getting

Comment: but i want to catch exact sql execption occuring in my sql query window as "Msg 121, Level 15, State 1, Procedure test_sp_syntaxtext, Line 124
The select list for the INSERT statement contains more items than the insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of INSERT columns.
"

Comment: You have to fix the ExecutionFailureException first. ExecutionFailureException happend before the command execution.

Answer (score 1):

```
catch (SqlException ex) { ... }
```

Comment: look at my edit section for this sqlexception will not be catched as the error occurs is of ExecutionFailureException

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the properties you find at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx

You will need to catch the `SqlException` instead of just any exception.

Answer (score 1):

When logging an exception it's a good idea to log the entire thing, especially the *stacktrace*. The stacktrace is the most important part. If you just log `ex.ToString()` you won't be discarding that information.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`catch (SqlException ex)           { }` instead of `catch (Exception ex)           { }`.

Have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.aspx) information about SqlException.

Answer (score 1):

Once again I am very late, but none of the answer looks right to me. OP context is SMO. With SMO, `SqlException` can be encapsulated as inner exceptions of ExecutionFailureException. That is why he is looking at `InnerException`.

Here is the solution I am using for logging `SqlException` details if present (with `Logger` being a log4net `ILog`).

Catch block:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.Error("Unhandled error", ex);
    LogSqlErrors(ex);
}
```

`LogSqlErrors` (note the last line, this is what takes care of inner exception):

```
private static void LogSqlErrors(Exception ex)
{
    if (ex == null)
        return;

    var sqlEx = ex as SqlException;
    if (sqlEx != null && sqlEx.Errors != null && sqlEx.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        var sqlErrs = new StringBuilder();
        sqlErrs.AppendFormat("SqlException contains {0} SQL error(s):", sqlEx.Errors.Count)
            .AppendLine();
        foreach (SqlError err in sqlEx.Errors)
        {
            sqlErrs.AppendLine("--------------------------------")
                .AppendFormat("Msg {0}, Level {1}, State {2}, Procedure '{4}', Line {5}",
                    err.Number, err.Class, err.State, err.Procedure, err.LineNumber)
                .AppendLine()
                .AppendLine(err.Message);
        }
        Logger.Warn(sqlErrs.ToString());
    }

    LogSqlErrors(ex.InnerException);
}
```

Unfortunately, if your sql commands string contains many batches (using `go` separators, as supported by SMO), this will not tell you which sql batch yields the error. (The error line number is computed for the failing batch, without taking into account lines count of previous batches.)

I have checked the way `ExecutionFailureException` are built (using a decompiler on SMO version 12): it could have stored this info, but it does not. So you can only guess.

Moreover, if you use the `ContinueOnError` option, errors are swallowed (not stored anywhere). Well, it would be great if SMO team could improve exception handling in their library.